# How do we import json from an NPM package in Angular 15?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, npm

I have a local package containing a `json` file, and I'm trying to load the json file into the Angular 15 `app.component.ts`.

I install the json file package in the Angular project like this:

```
npm i @fireflysemantics/fs-a-md
```

So now it's available under the `node_modules` of the Angular project.

The package declares the `main` content like this within the `package.json` file:

```
{
  ...
  "main": "target/content.json"
  ...
}
```

And I used to be able to load it like this in previous Angular versions:

```
import * as data from '@fireflysemantics/fs-a-md';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  content: any = (<any>data).default
}
```

However Angular 15 produces the error message:

```
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:2:23 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@fireflysemantics/fs-a-md' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import * as data from '@fireflysemantics/fs-a-md';
```

Any ideas?

Just to make sure the package is really installed, I ran the folowing ls:

```
oleersoy@Oles-MacBook-Pro al % ls node_modules/@fireflysemantics/fs-a-md/target 
CNAME               robots.txt
app.component.ts        route_data.ts
content.json            scully.fs-a-app.config.ts
deploy.js           sitemap.xml
index.html
oleersoy@Oles-MacBook-Pro al %
```

So it's definitely there ...

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick.  Had to go into `tsconfig.json` and set under `compilerOptions`:

```
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
```